# AWS ALB Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I configured an internet facing ALB in AWS with two listeners (80 and 443) and the target groups are in private network (10.0.1.0/24).  When http/https request are sent by ALB to the target group in 10.0.1.0 network, how the request is sent back to ALB?  ALB has a public IP, and the target group do not have a route to internet.  I can configure a NAT gateway and setup a route 0.0.0.0/0 to use the NAT gateway.  But the web response will go all the way to internet and then comeback to ALB.  Highly undesirable.  I can't put these instances in public facing subnet either.

Can some one help how this can be done?  I  thought of VPC endpoint, and configured one with the load balancer (I used ELB, as I couldn't find ALB endpoint service).  Now, the endpoint shows it has an IP in the 10.0.1.0 subnet.  However, I don't know how this will work.  Can someone suggest what's to be done.  Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual issue? Have you tried this yet to verify it is a problem? If the ALB can make a connection to the EC2 instances it will keep that connection open waiting for the response to come back. The EC2 instances do not have to create a separate outbound connection to the ALB to send the response, so there should be no issue doing what you are trying to do. As long as you are using Security Group rules, and not network ACLs, then the traffic back to the ALB will not be blocked.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure exactly what your question here is. But giving you a simple explanation of how AWS ELB works.

In both AWS Classic Load Balancers and Application Load Balancers, two connections are involved:

1. A connection between client (browser, etc) and ELB
2. A connection between ELB and backend target instances (webservers)

When creating an Internet facing ELB, you are given the option of selecting two subnets. These subnets should be public subnets which have a route to an Internet Gateway. The ELB will launch at least one ELB node in each of these subnets. Clients on the Internet will be able to connect to these ELB nodes using their public IPs through the IGW.

Once the ELB receives the request from the client, it forwards the request to its backend targets. This communication uses the PRIVATE IPs of the ELB nodes and the target instances. Therefore, even if the instances are in the private subnet, the ELB will still be able to forward requests to them because the connection is over private IPs which uses the 'local' route in the route tables. The response from the target then goes to the ELB over private IP, and is then forwarded to the client over public IP.

```
Client <--public IP--> ELB <--private IP--> Targets
```

The connection between client and ELB is over public IP, the connection between ELB and webservers is over private IPs which does not need a route to an IGW or NAT.

Don't worry about NAT Gateways for your private subnets. Just make sure the subnets you choose when creating the ELB are public and have a route to an internet gateway.

Comment: Thanks.  The missing link was the public subnet association to the ALB with private subnet instances as target groups.  This works but I didn't notice any launching of instances in the public subnet.  It simply works.

Comment: Awesome explaining! It helps me understand what's happened under the hood thoroughly. Thanks